# Ruby new unique array of nested array items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Looking for a way to reduce a nested list of arrays, into a single array of items that are unique, and drop any empty arrays.

Looking to reduce this array:

```
[[2700, 177, 2092, 176, 188], [123, 1234], []]
```

Down to this new array:

```
[2700, 177, 2092, 176, 188, 123, 1234]
```

Have tried `array.uniq.compact`, but did not work.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to flatten the array first.

```
array.flatten.uniq
```

A few notes:

- `Array#flatten` merges all child arrays into the top level array. Since empty arrays do not contain any elements, they will automatically be removed.
- `Array#compact` returns a new array with the `nil` elements removed.
- `Array#uniq` returns a new array with only unique elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`Array#flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-flatten)

> Returns a new array that is a one-dimensional flattening of self
>   (recursively).

```
=> [[2700, 177, 2092, 176, 188], [123, 1234], []].flatten
#> [2700, 177, 2092, 176, 188, 123, 1234]
```